# How do I change even line background colours in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I find the dark theme much easier to concentrate in, but I think I mucked something up a while ago and it turned the dark theme text editor into a monstrosity:

[image]

I tried clicking reset to defaults in this menu:

[image]

But it appears that that menu does not control this specific part because it did not change it back (Or god forbid it's supposed to look like this)

Does anyone know the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an extension installed that is providing that coloring. Go to Tools->Extensions and Updates and check if there's anything about alternating line colors (perhaps [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e0c81c8-4e71-450f-82aa-c9e8731b80f0)), and disable or uninstall it.

Comment: Ah, wow, can't believe I forgot that was installed. Thank you for reminding me! :(